# Creating new element with a dynamic extends class expression

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, web-component, custom-element

Is it possible to pass a **class *expression*** as parameter?

Have not tried the `eval` route yet..

```
// CardtsElements.Zone contains a valid class expression
// used to create a valid Zone Custom Element
let extend = (source, name, definitionClassExpression) => 
    customElements.define('CARDTS-' + name, 
                           class extends CardtsElements[source] definitionClassExpression);
                                                              ^^^^SYNTAX ERROR^^^^^^^^^^

// Create a new 'CARDTS-FOUNDATION' element extending 'CARDTS-ZONE'
extend('Zone','Foundation', {
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['suit','draggable','drop'];
    }
    constructor(){}
});
```

Comment: Maybe with Object.assign()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your *class expression* as a **class factory** function:

- a (arrow) `function`,
- with one parameter (`superclass`): the `class` you want to extend,
- that will return the new derived `class`.

```js
// CardtsElements.Zone contains a valid class expression
// used to create a valid Zone Custom Element
var CardtsElements = {
  'Zone': class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() { super() ; console.log('zone element created') }
      connectedCallback(){ console.log('connected Zone')}
      zone() { console.log( 'zone' ) }
  }
}

let extend = (source, name, classFactory) => 
    customElements.define('cardts-' + name, classFactory(CardtsElements[source])) 


// Create a new 'CARDTS-FOUNDATION' element extending 'CARDTS-ZONE'
extend('Zone','foundation', superclass => 
     class extends superclass {
         constructor() { super() ; console.log(this.localName + ' created') }
         static get observedAttributes() { return ['suit','draggable','drop'] }
         connectedCallback(){ 
            super.connectedCallback();
            console.log('connected',this.localName)
         }
         foundation() { console.log('foundation') }
     }
)

CF.zone()
CF.foundation()
```

```html
<cardts-foundation id=CF>Cardts Foundation</cardts-foundation>
```

Comment: Extremely sharp as ever. Couple of more days and the result of all your help in these past months is on GitHub

Comment: This is cool... To enhance your example I added 2 connectedCallbacks and a super call in your code to complete the functionality. My 52 playing cardts are now fully semantic HTML like: ``<King-of-Hearts />`` and ``<Ten-of-Spades />`` creating SVG cards (as data:image in an IMG element). I need to do some serious code cleanup to get this on GitHub