# CSS Selector for a partial CustomElement nodename

Tags: css-selectors, web-component, custom-element

**Update:** Went for a different solution:

`<img is=queen-of-hearts>`

Live at: https://card-ts.github.io/playingcardts

---

**this question is about working around CSS Selector limitations**

So my Custom Elements now make true symantic HTML:

[image]

Displaying:

[image]

*no external SVG files,

all 500KB SVG is (manually) slimmed and LZMA packed to 70KB into **ONE** Custom Element

all 52 cards (Custom Elements) are then created with [Supersharps class factory code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471966/creating-new-element-with-a-dynamic-extends-class-expression)*

## Next problem arises... What selectors to use?

I **can do**:

```css
    Queen-of-Hearts {
      transform: rotate(20deg)
    }
```

**But to highlight every King following a Queen (only one above) the CSS gets verbose:**

```css
        Queen-of-Spades+King-of-Spades,
        Queen-of-Hearts+King-of-Hearts,
        Queen-of-Diamonds+King-of-Diamonds,
        Queen-of-Clubs+King-of-Clubs,

        Queen-of-Hearts+King-of-Spades,
        Queen-of-Hearts+King-of-Hearts,
        Queen-of-Hearts+King-of-Diamonds,
        Queen-of-Hearts+King-of-Clubs,

        Queen-of-Diamonds+King-of-Spades,
        Queen-of-Diamonds+King-of-Hearts,
        Queen-of-Diamonds+King-of-Diamonds,
        Queen-of-Diamonds+King-of-Clubs,

        Queen-of-Clubs+King-of-Spades,
        Queen-of-Clubs+King-of-Hearts,
        Queen-of-Clubs+King-of-Diamonds,
        Queen-of-Clubs+King-of-Clubs {
            transform: scale(1.2);
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
```

### I would like to write CSS like:

```css
    Queen* + King* {
            transform: scale(1.2);
            border: 1px solid green;
    }
```

- Plenty of jQuery answers for 'partial selectors' around which just do a brute force search with JS
- I have searched [CSS4 Selectors](https://css4-selectors.com/selectors/), nothing that catches my eye
- I can (kinda brute force also) create all CSS rules with JS
- Is the only alternative to ignore the nodename and add (data)attributes or classnames?

**Note:** I have a version which does `<Queen-of-Hearts rank="Queen" suit="Hearts" />`
But it is not as semantically 'pleasant'

Interested in any pointers for an elegant solution to capture Solitaire or Poker rules in CSS,
no browser limitations,
this is a *'having fun exploring browser capabilities'* project...
once cleaned will be on GitHub

## Update

Went with the notation we overlooked: extending a Built-In element:

`<img is=queen-of-hearts>`

- Its auto closing
- is a single DOM element
- can be accessed with CSS selectors `img[is*=queen]`
- only restriction is= must be lowercase...

maybe even better than the notation of the Autonomous Custom Element I started with:

`<card-t cid=Queen-of-Hearts></card-t>`

**Both** (I must say 53 Elements) are included in the single 16 KB file:

### https://card-ts.github.io/playingcardts

Comment: Why don't you create CSS classes `queen` and `king`? Also, I would rather create a `<play-card type="King" color="Heart">` component. That would allow for a `[type="Queen"] +  [type="King"]` selector.

Comment: Also, creating a play-card component will help avoid a lot of code duplication.

Comment: tnx, Attributes is the alternative I mentioned.have that in v1.. no worries..  works fine.. still verbose CSS. With Supersharps code example I created those 52 elements today... and hit this 'I want dynamic nodename selector' question. ----  Just like WCs extend from HTMLelement these 52 card classes extend from one Cardt class (not even shadowDOM as the SVG goes into on IMG),... It will be on GitHub in a week or 2 or 3 for anyone to pick apart and push improvements. Objective is to learn.. learn..learn.. It is not a get-it-into-production project. Seen many 'cards' projects that are worse :-)

Comment: You could set attributes `<king-of-spades black king spades></..>`, then your selector would be `[queen] + [king]`. @connexo according to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices you shouldn't self-apply classes (state should be expressed through attributes).

Comment: tnx all. For now I don't see value in ``<Queen-of-Hearts>`` Am refactoring to ``<card-ts queen hearts red></card-ts>`` As thebjorn referred to in developer docs: ► *The class attribute is generally considered to be owned by the developer using your element, and writing to it yourself may inadvertently stomp on developer classes*

Comment: The value of <Queen-of-Heart> is that it makes the playing card immutable/read-only. Also the (very subjective) 'best' practice not to use classes in not relevant in this case: it's not the component author who adds the classes, but the component user (human or container app) that add them in order to achieve CSS selection easily. In the end it is a dilemma between semantic and usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you finally decide to use a unique custom element name as suggested by Connexo, maybe it would useful to keep *named* attributes to deifne the rank and suit.

```
<playing-card rank="Queen" suit="Hearts">
```

You could then define properties that will reflect both-ways the attributes values.

```
card.rank === card.getAttribute( 'rank' )
```

This way it would be easier to find the value of a card than if you use *attributes as values*.

Consider this notation:

```
<playing-card queen hearts></playing-card>
```

Problem: what is its value?

```
let card = game.querySelector( 'playing-card' )    
if ( card.getAttribute( 'spades ') )
     suit = spades
else if ( card.getAttributes( 'diamonds' ) )
     ...
```

---

Alternately, you could use a single `name` attribute:

**html**

```
<playing-card name="10-of-spades">
```

**javascript**

```
//easy manipulation
let card = document.querySelector( 'playing-card' ) 
let [rank, suit] = card.name.split( '-of-' )
```

**css**

```
//easy selection (...for advanced CSS users)
[name|=king] + [name|=queen]  //Queens after a King
[name|=1]                     //Aces
[name$=spades]                //Spades
```

Comment: went with the notation we overlooked: extending a Built-In element ``<img is=queen-of-hearts>`` Its auto closing, is a single DOM element, can be accessed with CSS selectors, only restriction ``is=`` must be lowercase... maybe even better than the ``<card-t cid=Queen-of-Hearts></card-t>`` notation. Both (I must say 53 Elements) are included in the single 16 KB file: https://card-ts.github.io/playingcardts/

Comment: This solution though will NOT fit for a case every component have its own behaviour, in example: I have a set of custom controls ALL beginning with "ef-" if I want to select ALL these custom controls without adding specific "class", is it even possible with CSS?