# Web Components : extending native elements

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm trying to create a web component that extends the div element and I found [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986046/how-to-create-new-instance-of-an-extended-class-of-custom-elements) about how to extend native elements (a button in this case). However, I cannot make it work. And, according to the update in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988275/2768271), it should work.

If you look at the results in this simplified code snippet, it is just rendered as a simple inline element with text. 
And if you open the Chrome console and look in the properties tab it is also clear that it does not inherit from HTMLButtonElement (which it should). What's wrong?

```js
class FancyButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
    constructor() {
        super(); // always call super() first in the ctor.
        this.addEventListener('click', e => this.innerHTML = "I was clicked");
    }
}

customElements.define('fancy-button', FancyButton, { extends: 'button' });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <fancy-button>Click me</fancy-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `<button is='fancy-button'>Test</button>`

Comment: Thanks it works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are 2 types of Custom Elements [MDN: Using Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

- Autonomous Custom Elements
- Customized Built-In Elements
  [Polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/built-in-element) required for Safari
  because Apple, with valid argument, will not implement these

**One registry to rule them all**

(for now) There is only one registry so your **Customized element** is registered as `fancy-button`;
**But** can **NOT** be used with **Autonomous notation:** `<fancy-button></fancy-button/>`

`Firefox DOES allow a mix of both notations BUT only if define() is used AFTER the Custom Elements was parsed in the DOM`

---

#### From docs section: **Extending Native HTML Elements:**

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extendhtml

Consumers of a customized built-in element can use it in several ways.
They can declare it by adding the is="" attribute on the native tag:

```
    <!-- This <button> is a fancy button. -->
    <button is="fancy-button" disabled>Fancy button!</button>
```

create an instance in JavaScript:

```
    // Custom elements overload createElement() to support the is="" attribute.
    let button = document.createElement('button', {is: 'fancy-button'});
    button.textContent = 'Fancy button!';
    button.disabled = true;

    // have to do this yourself!! IF you want to use it as a selector
    button.setAttribute("is","fancy-button");

    document.body.appendChild(button);
```

or use the new operator:

```
    let button = new FancyButton();
    button.textContent = 'Fancy button!';
    button.disabled = true;
```

#### Conclusion

There are 2 types of Custom Elements, **you can't mix**

You either go for:

- Autonomous Custom Element: `<fancy-button></fancy-button>`

or

- Customized Built-In Element `<button is=fancy-button></button>`

#### for Customized Built-In Elements

`document.createElement('fancy-button') instanceof HTMLButtonElement`

returns **false**

and

`<fancy-button>lightDOM</fancy-button>`

`document.querySelector('fancy-button')`

returns the element (if in the DOM),
but the element is processed as an undefined Element displaying the lightDOM contents

---

#### Example using both types of Custom Elements

In https://cardmeister.github.io I used both:

`<card-t rank=queen suit=hearts></card-t>`

`<img is=queen-of-hearts/>`

Thus I could **not** do:

`<queen-of-hearts></queen-of-hearts>`

The latter has little value, with IMG the `is` attribute can be used for CSS targetting.
[CSS Selector for a partial CustomElement nodename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518906/css-selector-for-a-partial-customelement-nodename)

Comment: Am interested to hear your reasoning. ``is=`` notation makes my other project real easy. Single selfclosing DOM elements: ``<img is=white-king/> , <img is=black-king/> ... etc``

Comment: Nice explanation. Any solution for compatibility html "is" attribute in internet explorer?

Comment: Sorry, don't do IE anymore. The post is from a year ago... At the moment I have no serious use for ``is`` (Customized Built-In Elements). Apple still refuses to implement them. So I use Autonomous Elements only.

Comment: One thing for ``is`` I learned. After you ``createElement`` a Customized DOM Element, you have to do ``button.setAttribute("is","fancy-button")`` yourself IF you want to use it as a selector. Have added it to above code. I guess because the element was already created as ``fancy-button``, and ``is`` is **not** an observedAttribute. You can't **change** an element into another element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, you have made me see things clearer. I think I'm finally going to find another way