# How to properly extend HTMLImageElement

Tags: javascript, image, safari, web-component, custom-element

Extending HTMLImageElement directly works okay for Chrome, Firefox etc.

```
export default class CustomImg extends HTMLImageElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

However it does not work at Safari which says super() is an illegal constructor. According to MDN Image() is the proper constructor for HTMLImageElement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement). I tried to extend Image as well. However even though it does not print out any errors, it just does not behave as a CustomElement.

Any ideas on how to create a custom element on top of HTMLImageElement that can work for both Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 different flavored Web Components:
details see [Web Components : extending native elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619025/web-components-extending-native-elements/56628245#56628245)

- Autonomous Elements (extend from HTMLElement)
- Customized Built-In Elements (extend from any Element)

But Apple/WebKit will not implement the latter as stated in **2016**:

https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/509

[image]